# Fill CoreData with a large SQL database

Tags: mysql, sqlite, core-data

I have a large 180k row SQL (mysql) database that I want to use in CoreData. Can I create the SQLite database using Xcode, then use an SQLight client app to connect to that database, and fill it using my mysql data?

Or is there a better way to efficiently import a large data set to a CoreData store?

It will only be filled once and the data should reside on-device.

The reason I want to do this is because I am building an iOS app that needs to read from a persistent store containing most words in the English language. Along with the word, each row will contain a few other things. The app will never need to write to the database, just read from it, but it will need to read from it very quickly.

From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html) it appears this is not recommended (or maybe impossible): "do not manipulate an existing Core Data-created SQLite store using the native SQLite API"

**Update:**
Another option that I am currently working on is to export the MySQL database to json using phpmyadmin (or another tool). Then load that json file in to the project. When the app loads (hopefully just the first time it is used), push the data from the json file in to Core Data.

Comment: Would Firebase be a better option? I can convert the sql file to JSON, then upload JSON to Firebase easily. I just have to learn how to download the firebase database to the device so it works offline.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* reverse-engineer Core Data and produce a Core Data sqlite file directly if you really wanted to, but as you quoted from Apple docs this is not a good idea.

It would be *easier* to simply write a little macOS command-line tool which includes the same Core Data data model as your iOS app.  This tool would read your MySQL database and write it to a Core Data SQLite file, which you would then ship with your iOS app.